# How to run qt application on embedded linux target?

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, embedded-linux

I am new to QT embedded development. I have windows desktop QT development knowledge.

I am trying to run examples on target board, but not working. Below are the details.

- Board- Salvator-XS/ARM
- OS Image Build - Yocto 3.9 and B2qt.
- Display - Lilliput Touch
- Board Connected to Display using HDMI

```
root@salvator-x:/data/user/qt# ./PokyWidget -platform Wayland-EGL  
Using Wayland-EGL
Using the 'xdg-shell-v6' shell integration  
./PokyWidget: **symbol lookup error: /usr/lib/libQt5Gui.so.5: undefined symbol: hb_font_set_ptem**  
root@salvator-x:/data/user/qt#
```

Below the Environment variables - Is there anything I am missing to run QT application on embedded target?

```
root@salvator-x:/data/user/qt# printenv 
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/lib  
OLDPWD=/data/user/qt/textinput  
EDITOR=vi  
XDG_SESSION_ID=c2  
HUSHLOGIN=FALSE  
USER=root  
PWD=/data/user/qt  
HOME=/home/root  
MAIL=/var/spool/mail/root  
SHELL=/bin/sh  
TERM=xterm  
SHLVL=1  
LOGNAME=root  
XDG_RUNTIME_DIR=/run/user/0  
PATH=/usr/aarch64-poky- linux/bin:/etc:/lib:/bin:/usr/lib:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/sbin:/usr/aarch64-poky-linux/bin:/etc:/lib:/bin:/usr/lib:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/sbin  
PS1=\u@\h:\w$  
_=/usr/bin/printenv
```

Comment: How is the Qt built? The missing symbol is from the Harfbuzz library.

Comment: I think Qt build was done without any issues (it was not me). I see Harfbuzz libs on the target.

Comment: In short, we need more information... When you say "I see Harfbuzz libs on the target", show us the path to them and show us that symbol is in them.
Also, show us the compilation of your application. How are you cross building and linking against the cross-built libs? How was Qt cross-built? How was Harfbuzz cross-built?

Answer (score 0):

This look like a known issue from Qt, https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-72956.